# I can't move the handles in half and graph mode, how do I fix that?

Tags: animation, keyframes

On occasion, I find myself unable to move the handles of the keyframes, only the entire keyframe itself. It's probably an easy fix but I'm a bit new so things such as this confuse me.[image: Image of the Half and Graph side of screen]

Comment: To manipulate a single handle and not affect it's twin - Select the handle. Press V F G and drag it about with the mouse.  (No mouse buttons are required)

Comment: Maybe you have proportional editing activated, so moving one handle affects the entire keyframe. Press O or Alt O to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The same problem. I solved it by turning *Proportional Editing FCurves* off. The shortcut is <kbd>O</kbd>.